# .outerWidth() returning different widths with different viewport sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, outerwidth

I have a horizontally scrolling gallery of images. The `<div>` which contains all of the images has its width generated dynamically by summing up the outerWidths of all the children.

Here is how the gallery is set up:

```html
<div class="categoryImageArea">       
 <div class="categoryImage" onclick="window.location = 'http://localhost/kitkittle/product/test-1'">
  <img src="http://localhost/kitkittle/uploads/images/full/58172669e54ea075971494d6293444f5.jpg"><br> 
  <h3>Half Bubble -  $50.00</h3> 
 </div>
 <div class="categoryImage" onclick="window.location = 'http://localhost/kitkittle/product/bubble-mitosis'">
  <img src="http://localhost/kitkittle/uploads/images/full/23aacfda65e43671bede87bc18902b81.jpg"><br> 
  <h3>Bubble Mitosis -  $300.00</h3> 
 </div>
 <div class="categoryImage" onclick="window.location = 'http://localhost/kitkittle/product/bubble-on-water'">
  <img src="http://localhost/kitkittle/uploads/images/full/1e2dc5352f831ebacd3ccbb7a9b4717a.jpg"><br> 
  <h3>Bubble on Water -  $10.00</h3> 
 </div>
 <div class="categoryImage" onclick="window.location = 'http://localhost/kitkittle/product/bubble-on-water1'">
  <img src="http://localhost/kitkittle/uploads/images/full/69f7b2c3b640444dd5a23c3037c3cc84.jpg"><br> 
  <h3>Bubble on Ocean -  $210.00</h3> 
 </div>
 <div class="categoryImage" onclick="window.location = 'http://localhost/kitkittle/product/swimming-bubbles'">
  <img src="http://localhost/kitkittle/uploads/images/full/2d66a56b9f51f29ad5c6f58c82b2ab39.jpg"><br> 
  <h3>Swimming Bubbles -  $0.00</h3> 
 </div>
</div>
```

The width of `categoryImageArea` is generated using the following function:

```js
function change(){
 if($(window).width() > 768){ 
  var width = 0; 
  $('.categoryImage').each(function(index, element){ 
   width += $(element).outerWidth(true); 
  }); 
  $('.categoryImageArea').width(width); 
 }
 else{ 
  $('.categoryImageArea').width('100%'); 
 } 
}
```

When my browser window is maximized (1900 x 1280), this works great: 
[image]

[image]

However, when my browser window is half the size, it does not work. (sorry, the screenshot is hard to see -- the last two are pushed to the next line). 
[image]

I was perplexed about why this would be, so I made the JQuery `change()` function (above) `alert` the value of `width` as it adds values to it in both cases. It's strange.

- Large viewport (good): 0 > 984 > 1969 > 2953 > 3937 > 4921
- Half viewport (bad): 0 > 656 > 1312 > 1968 > 2624 > 3280

So my question is: what on earth is making the value of `$(element).outerWidth(true)`  SO different just because my browser viewport is different?

For reference, the styles being applied to `categoryImage` are:

```css
.categoryImage {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2em;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. For whatever reason, `img { max-width: 100%; }` was altering the value of the `outerWidth();` (only in certain instances). To fix the issue, I set `.categoryImage img{ max-width: none; }` and that solved the weird problems I was having!

Answer (score 0):

On .categoryImage replace display:inline-block with float:left. Then on . categoryImageArea add a class of overflow:hidden or a clearfix.

```
.categoryImage {
    float:left;
    margin: 2em;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Another option would be to try imageloaded: http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/

Comment: What is the difference between that method and what I currently have in place? I changed it to `float: left;` but the issue persists.

Comment: I've often had issues with the display inline-block and float usually fixed it. After posting that, I got to thinking, maybe you have a similar problem that is common with the masonry cascading grid layout - in where, if the JS loads before the images the width doesn't calc correctly.

Comment: I thought that as well. So I tried to make the `change()` function apply after `$('.categoryImageArea').ready(function(){` but this also does not work. I have a feeling that somehow the window size is changing the images. I'm not sure how, but since it is a responsive site, there could be CSS percentages changing the widths of `categoryImage`. Not sure, still haven't figured it out.